# Add a thin line on the top of Action bar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I would like to add a thin line with purple color at the top of my action bar like this :

[image]

UPDATE

Here is the code of my theme.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText">
        <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/relativeLayoutBg</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Action bar is separate hierarchy from what are you setting inside setContentView. There are very little possibility of doing it

Comment: create 9patch image with thin line. add that image to action bar background

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setBackgroundDrawable` on the actionBar.

You can create a 9-patch drawable that will stretch out to look like that. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

EDIT:To set this in xml in styles.xml add

to the app theme add

`<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>`

and below add

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/my_action_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of code that i have to add in my xml file to customize my action bar ? Thanks

Comment: If you want to do it in XML you will have to do it in the style.xml. It's not an option in layout XML or manifest as far as I know.

Comment: see my edit, important part is to use a drawable in the background instead of a colour

Comment: It would be a PNG file not an XML file. It would be a 9-patch as per the link in the answer (i'll edit to make the link more obvious)